# knockoutJS subscribe observable

Tags: woocommerce, knockout.js, subscribe, gravityforms

I am new to KnockoutJS and on a steep learning curve at the moment. I am using Gravity Forms and the Nested Forms Addon from Gravity Wiz. I have linked the Nested Form to products setup using WooCommerce.

Some of my products are Bundled products so when I select these items in my Nested Form I am trying to add the bundled products linked products to my Parent Form and not the bundled product itself. This is where Knockout JS comes in. I have subscribed to the ViewModel so I can see if entries are added/edited/deleted.

I can see my bundled product in the entries as shown in the code below, before this point I am doing an Ajax call to the server and I have got the list of linked products but I don't know how to append/bind them to my viewModel? Any help appreciated.

```
self.init = function() {

    //alert("Its a bundled item");
    get the content of the Nest Form Modal
    var gpnf = window.GPNestedForms_2_1;

    //subscribe to the ViewModel
    gpnf.viewModel.entries.subscribe( function( entries ) {
        // I can see my bundled product here
        console.log( entries );

        self.AppendBundledItem(entries, BundleProdArray);
    } );

}

self.AppendBundledItem = function( entries, bp ) {
    //loop through bp and append to entries then return to ViewModel
}

self.init();
```

Comment: do you know how to use an [`observableArray`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)?

Comment: hi @heyjude, If it's OK I will answer that by referencing the code above, "entries" is an observable array, am I correct? `gpnf.viewModel.entries.subscribe( function( entries ) {`

Comment: When I console.log entries I get the following: [{…}]
0: 
 1: {label: "Steve", value: "28|4015"}
 2: {label: "6", value: "6"}
 3: {label: "&#8364; 24.090,00", value: {…}}
 5: {label: "Till", value: "Till"}
 id: "260"
 total: 48180
 f1: {label: "Steve", value: "28|4015"}
 f2: {label: "6", value: "6"}
 f3: {label: "&#8364; 24.090,00", value: {…}}
 f5: {label: "Till", value: "Till"}
 fid: "260"
 ftotal: 48180
 __proto__: Object
 length: 1
 __proto__: Array(0)

Comment: did you log `console.log(entries)` or `console.log(entries())`? that's an important difference. assuming you did the former one, then it's just a simple array, while it should be an `observableArray`.

Comment: I did `console.log(entries)`, if I do `console.log(entries())` then I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: entries is not a function

Comment: thought so. then now go ahead, read about [`observableArray`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html), and implement `entries` into such object.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking up converting it now.